# Copy issue to SharePoint UNC location

Tags: sharepoint, copy-paste, unc

I'm trying to copy a zip file using command prompt from source to destination. 
Size of the zip file is 1.14 GB.

COPY \Server1\DataFeeds\Dec\feed1.zip C:\Folder1
This works fine. I can see the zip file copied over to C:\Folder1 & it shows size correct, i.e. 1.14GB

COPY \Server1\DataFeeds\Dec\feed1.zip \upload.website.com\DavWWWRoot\Documents\Dec
This does not work as expected. I can see the zip file copied over to SharePoint unc location (\upload.website.com\DavWWWRoot\Documents\Dec), but it's just EMPTY FILE - SIZE 0 BYTES

What could be the reason that the copy not working for SharePoint location as destination?
How can I fix this? Thanks.

More Info: Here is the error logged in windows system log: Any help will be highly appreciated.

Application popup: cmd.exe - Delayed Write Failed : 
Windows was unable to save all the data for the file. The data has been lost. 
This error may be caused by a failure of your computer hardware or network connection. 
Please try to save this file elsewhere.

Comment: I have 3 same size file